# Determinant of $A^4 - A^3$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

I have a matrix

```
A= ( 1,1,-1 ; 0,1,1 ; -1;0;2)
```

For which, obviously, I can find eigen values, determinant, ...

I been asked to calculate:

$\det(A^4 - A^3)$

This was a question on an exam, so I'm assuming it's not to solve explicitly but instead using determinant properties, how can I do that since,

In general $\det(A + B) /= \det(A) + \det(B)$ ?

Comment: Hint: Use $\det(AB)=\det(A)\det(B)$.

Comment: But there's still a minus sign in there

Comment: Compute $\det(A-I)$ separately.

Comment: $A^4 - A^3 = (A-I)(A^3), \det (A-I)(A^3) = (\det (A-I))(\det A)^3,  \det A = 0$

Comment: Snce you say you've calculated eigenvalues, then $\det(A-I) = (\lambda_1 - 1) (\lambda_2 - 1) (\lambda_3 - 1)$.  Or more directly, $\det(A^4 - A^3) = (\lambda_1^4 - \lambda_1^3) (\lambda_2^4 - \lambda_2^3) (\lambda_3^4 - \lambda_3^3)$.

Answer (score 4):

Try factoring $$A^4 - A^3 = A^3(A-I)$$

Using the multiplicative property of the determinant
$$\det\big(A^3(A-I)\big) = \det(A)^3\det(A-I)$$

So worst case all you need to calculate is $\det(A)$ and $\det(A - I)$.

For your particular $A$, calculating its determinant is immediate from the observation that
$$\text{(1st row of $A$)} + \text{(3rd row of $A$)} = \text{(2nd row of $A$)}$$

Comment: And once you have calculated det(A) there is nothing left to do!